# Redirect and locale issues when using Valet / Caddy Server

Tags: localization, redirect, caddy, valet

I'm trying to setup our Craft CMS dev environment with [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet) which is just a wrapper for Caddy Server and dnsmasq.

I seem to be running into some redirect/locale issues that's preventing these pages from loading. The rest of the site and the CMS admin itself is working fine.

I've previously had things setup on apache and have followed the [localization guides](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide) but I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that caddy server doesn't honor `.htaccess` files so I need to add some rewrite rules in my `Caddyfile` for the various locales.

When trying to load the regional sites it's just giving me a 404.

Has anyone else got this working?

Answer (score 1):

Discussion with solutions here https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/179